# Animating a defined path's d attribute doesn't work on firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, svg-animate, smil

I'm animating a `d` attribute of a `path` that is wrapped around a `defs` tag and linked using a
few `use` tags. This works fine on Chrome, however no animation on Firefox. I tried this with relative and absolute paths to no avail.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <defs>
    <path id="a" d="M0,20 H200 V70 H0z" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a" />
  <animate xlink:href="#a" attributeName="d" values="M0,20 H200 V70 H0z; M0,20 H200 V45 H0z" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

Is the only way to make this work is by repeating the `path` and animating them all or is there a way to make this work on Firefox?

Comment: I think you'd need to repeat the paths. At the moment SMIL changes to the things that a <use> element points to do not trigger the <use> to re-render.

Comment: @RobertLongson - I see, thank you! Grateful for your comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by **@Robert Longson**

> I think you'd need to repeat the paths. At the moment SMIL changes to
> the things that a  element points to do not trigger the  to
> re-render.

Therefore, it is necessary to transfer the animation directly inside the `<path>` tags

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <defs>
    <path id="a" d="M0,20 H200 V70 H0z" >
      <animate
      attributeName="d"
      values="
            M0,20 H200 V70 H0z;
            M0,20 H200 V45 H0z"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            dur="1s"
            begin="0s"
            fill="freeze" />
    </path>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a" />
 
</svg>
```

*Start animation after click*

```html
<svg id ="svg1" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <defs>
    <path id="a" d="M0,20 H200 V70 H0z" >
      <animate
      attributeName="d"
      values="
            M0,20 H200 V70 H0z;
            M0,20 H200 V45 H0z"
            keyTimes="0;1"
            dur="1s"
            begin="svg1.click"
            fill="freeze" />
    </path>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#a" />
 
</svg>
```